# how to add variable to url in javascript and get using @PathVariable

Tags: javascript, java

this is javascript code i want add integer to url

```
function editAdmin(id) {
    document.AdminSuccess.action="editAdmin?id="+id;
    document.AdminSuccess.submit();
}
```

And this is my java method

```
@RequestMapping("/editAdmin/{id}")
public String editAdmin(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model) {}
```

Comment: in javascript you are adding RequestParam but in java you are trying to get PathVariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript adds `id` as a *query* parameter, while your Java code expects the parameter in the request *path*.

To fix it, change your JavaScript to

```js
document.AdminSuccess.action="editAdmin/"+id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the quotes those are back tick symbols used in place of quotes and they permit you to add a variable without the + symbol, you just have to put them in curly braces and precede with a $ symbol

```js
document.AdminSuccess.action=`editAdmin/${id}`;
```